# How to use Collections in java to sort list populated from a class

Tags: java, arrays, list, sorting, collections

I am having trouble trying to sort the following list.
Simply using Collections.sort(mylist); is showing an error which I am unable to understand as I'm a beginner to java

```
Myclass x1 = new Myclass("8", "12");
Myclass x2 = new Myclass("6", "9");
Myclass x3 = new Myclass("11", "14");
List<Myclass> mylist = Arrays.asList(x1, x2, x3);
```

How to sort "mylist" such that it is stored in the following order-(6,9),(8,12),(11,14)
i.e according to the first value of the tuples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your object don't have natural order (like integers), you need to use a specify a comparator mechanism, yourself.

```
Collections.sort(myList, new Comparator<Myclass>() {

    public int compare(Myclass o1, Myclass o2) {
        // I don't know how you access the first integer in your 'MyClass'
        // replace by your own.
        int number1 = o1.getFirstElement();
        int number2 = o2.getFirstElement();
        if (number1  < number2 ) {
            return -1;
        } else if (number1  > number2 ) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
});
```

You always compare two objects, so you can only have -1 1 and 0 as result, even if the difference between two objects is bigger:
Comparing (6,9) and (8,12) will result the comparator returning 1 when the difference is 2
Comparing (8,12) and (11,14 will result the comparator returning 1 when the difference is 3
And the sorting operation will still be correct.

The rules are:

- sgn(compare(x,y)) = -sgn(compare(y,x))
- if compare(x,y) > 0 and compare(y, z) -> compare(x,z) > 0
- if comapre(x,z) = 0 -> sgn(compare(x,y)) = -sgn(compare(y,x))

Comment: You cannot compare strings with >

Comment: Umang: Really? Then maybe you want to re-formulate your question. Over there you ask about numbers passed as strings to the constructor.

Comment: Loic: You can simply return `number1 - number2` instead of comparing them and returning -1/0/1.

Comment: It works as well, except if the difference betweenthe two integers is two big. That's unlikely though.

Answer (score 3):

```
Collections.sort(myList, myComparator);
```

`myComparator` should be your custom implementation of the `Comparator` interface.

Assuming that `Myclass` has a `getFirstValue` method your `Comparator` can be:

```
public class MyComaparator implements Comparator<Myclass> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Myclass arg0, Myclass arg1) {
        return arg0.getFirstValue() - arg1.getFirstValue();
    }

}
```

Please note that I also assumed that `getFirstValue()` does not return `null`. The validation part is up to you. I suggest you should use primitives in your `Tuple` implementation to solve this problem easily.

The official docs is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).

Comment: could you please explain in more detail or point me towards some tutorial website where I could learn how to use a custom comparator. I'm still trying to understand the nuances of java

Comment: I think this will do for you: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=10

Answer (score 3):

Do you really want to pass the numbers as strings, but then compare them as numbers if possible?

I assume `Myclass` has the following interface:

```
class Myclass {
    public Myclass(String first, String second) {..}
    public String getFirst() {..}
    public String getSecond() {..}
}
```

then implement your custom `Comparator` as follows. Since you are comparing strings but considering numbers, use the [AlphanumComparator](http://www.davekoelle.com/alphanum.html) (place the java implementation into some package):

```
public class MyComparator implements Comparator<Myclass> {
   private final static AlphanumComparator alphaNum = new AlphanumComparator();

   @Override
   public int compare(Myclass a, Myclass b) {
      return alphaNum.compare( a.getFirst(), b.getFirst() );
   }
}
```

and you can call:

```
Collections.sort(myList, new MyComparator())
```

Or you can have your class implement the [`Comparable` interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) and then Collections.sort(myList) would sort it according the `compareTo` method of that interface.

However, if your question is not asked correctly, and `Myclass` is actually a pair of integers (not strings), then you can simply define your comparator as follows:

```
public class MyComparator implements Comparator<Myclass> {
   @Override
   public int compare(Myclass a, Myclass b) {
      return a.getFirst() - b.getFirst();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using the **comparable** or the **comparator** interface. As yours is a custom object you have to tell the `Collections.sort` method as to what basis it should compare two objects in the collection.
[Here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/) is a good example on how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Two methods you can use to implement sort function with your class **Myclass**.

**Method#1** --> Use Myclass to implement `Comparable`, and write  custom comparison in compareTo method. Like,

Myclass ==>

```
public class Myclass implements Comparable {

private String value1;
private String value2;

public Myclass(String value1, String value2) {
    super();
    this.value1 = value1;
    this.value2 = value2;
}

public String getValue1() {
    return value1;
}

public void setValue1(String value1) {
    this.value1 = value1;
}

public String getValue2() {
    return value2;
}

public void setValue2(String value2) {
    this.value2 = value2;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Object o) {

    Myclass cl = (Myclass)o;
    return Integer.valueOf(value1) - Integer.valueOf(cl.getValue1()) ;
}

}
```

Test code==>

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Myclass x1 = new Myclass("8", "12");
    Myclass x2 = new Myclass("6", "9");
    Myclass x3 = new Myclass("11", "14");
    List<Myclass> mylist = Arrays.asList(x1, x2, x3);

            //Sort list
    Collections.sort(mylist);

            //Print List content
    for( Myclass cla : mylist )
    {
        System.out.printf("(%s,%s)", cla.getValue1(),cla.getValue2());
    }
}
}
```

Output in Console==>

```
(6,9)(8,12)(11,14)
```

**`Use this method, you can use Collections.sort(myList); to sort the object in list`.**

**Method#2** -->

**Write a customer Comparator if you do not want make Myclass implement Comparable.**

Use this method, you can use `Collections.sort(myList,customComparator);` to sort the object in list.

Regarding Method#2, **`Adam`** has provided example above. I am not going to provide it here.